# mingw "could not find a working compiler"

Tags: mingw, libraries, gmp

I'm trying to compile a third party library for use in c++ (gmp). I installed mingw and set the path variable. Now I go to compile the library, so I launch mingw, navigate to the folder where my library files are saved (there is a configure file in this folder), and type

> ./configure --prefix=${gmp_install}

expecting that this will compile the library and create a make file. But then after a couple of steps of progress, I get this error:

> could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

Of course, I looked at this log. There are few lines, but none of them mean anything to me.

Can anyone help me to figure this out? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the answer to my question is that I didn't have gcc installed. Since I'm trying to work through code::blocks, this video was exactly what I needed:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2XLvEcSrgo&feature=related

(still haven't got the gmp library installed, but that's due to other issues).